# Doctrine.yaml" does not contain valid YAML: A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value

Tags: symfony, doctrine, yaml

I have seen similair questions being asked but did not find my answer.
Most were typo's of some kind and that could be true for me but ive been staring at this for an hour now and cannot find one, maybe someone else can I would really appreciate it!

```
  doctrine:
      dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                #User DB
                 url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                 driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                 server_version: '5.7'
                 charset: utf8mb4
            mededelingen:
                #mededelingen DB
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_MEDEDELINGEN_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
             default:
                 connection: default
                     mappings:
                         users:
                             is_bundle: false
                             type: annotation
                             dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                             prefix: 'App\Entity\User'
                             alias: App
             mededelingen:
                 connection: mededelingen
                     mappings:
                         Mededelingen:
                             is_bundle: false
                             type: annotation
                             dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                             prefix: 'App\Entity\Mededeling'
                             alias: Mededeling
```

line 41 (near " alias: Mededeling")

Comment: Which of these lines causes the error?

Comment: Sorry! totally forgot to add that line 41 (near " alias: Mededeling")

Comment: That means: if you removed the very last line, no error occurs?

Comment: I tried that but then it wil just say  at line 41 (near " ")

Comment: And have you tried to remove **more** lines to see when that error is resolved?

Comment: I get a different error when i delete everything thats under auto_mapping:true default:

Comment: Have you tried to check the indention of that code? In my configuration, I see another line of `mappings:` between the auto mapping and the list of mappings

Comment: I tried but cannot find a problem right now

Comment: What do you mean by "tried"? Please share the proper file you are using - in YAML, even the indentation of lines is pretty important, and the given file doesn't respect that (starting in the very first line, where `dbal` should be nested a level deeper than `doctrine`)

Comment: Something went wrong there dbal is in fact nested a level deeper than doctrine in my file, what ive been trying is looking at other doctrine.yaml examples but I cant really find one that resembles mine to try and figure out where my problem lies

Comment: Then please share the file **exactly** as you are using it

Comment: Yes I edited it, for some reason when using the coding blocks it sets doctrine: and dbal: under eachother. This is my exact file

Comment: And have you tried to adjust the configuation  as recommended? Add `mappings:` after `auto_mapping: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fix your issue using my linter.

First, you missed the property `entity_managers` after `orm`, then I had to move `naming_strategy` and `auto_mapping`

`auto_mapping` can only be used on one entity manager so I set it on default.

The result which cause no issue for me:

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                #User DB
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            mededelingen:
                #mededelingen DB
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_MEDEDELINGEN_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    users:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\User'
                        alias: App
            mededelingen:
                connection: mededelingen
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    Mededelingen:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Mededeling'
                        alias: Mededeling
```